# Xamarin - .NET Standard - Use Azure DevOps Services with VssAadCredential -

Tags: xamarin, azure-active-directory, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I want to create a Xamarin.Forms app where I have to login to a specific Azure DevOps environment/project.

To try out the Azure DevOps Service library I first created a **Console App (.NET Framework 4.7.2)** to login to the Azure DevOps environment/project. The following code was used for login process (+ extra code to validate the connection actualy works).

```
public void Login(string _userName, string _pwd)
{
    ProjectHttpClient projectClient;

    this.Credentials = new VssAadCredential(_userName, _pwd);
    this.Connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(this.DevOpsPath), this.Credentials);
    this.InitReferences(this.ProjectName);

    projectClient = this.Connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
    this.ProjectReference = projectClient.GetProjects(null, top: 1).Result.Where(item => item.Name == this.ProjectName).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When I use the same piece of code in the **Xamarin.Forms App (.NET Standard 2.1)** it no longer works and I get the following error when executing the last line:

> One or more errors occurred. (Could not resolve type with token
>   0100008d from typeref (expected class
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions'
>   in assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory,
>   Version=3.19.4.11002, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'))

When using the **VssBasicCredential** with a personal acces token, the code runs as expected. However I would prefer using the VssAadCredential and not the VssBasicCredential.

I'm not aware that the VssAadCredential is not supported in .NET Standard and can find no documentation relating to the issue.

Has anyone had a similar experience that might solve this problem or can anyone provide me with some documentation declaring that this cannot work as of yet?